# Displaying a partial line of text

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I display the bottom half of a line of text in a text area or label? In my CSS, I have this

```
.label {
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 7px;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
}

<label class="label">TEST CODE</label>
```

What this does is display the top half of the label as if the line was cutoff. For example, the letter O would be displayed as a semicircle arc similar to an n. I have a need for this type of display and it works for me.

What I need to do is display just the bottom part of the line so a semicircle arc on the letter O would look something like a u. I can't use a mask because I'm displaying an image beneath the label so it has to have a transparent background. I tried padding-bottom but that didn't help. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add an example of the HTML you are manipulating as it will be helpful in providing a relative answer.

Comment: Perhaps not what you're asking for, but you could wrap the text in another container and move it up, You'd need to set the container to overflow: hidden, also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding, you are trying to crop the top half of the text horizontally rather than cutting off the bottom half.

To do this, you need to include an `overflow: hidden` value if you wish to 'crop' elements. In addition, you will want to set the `line-height` value for text elements to 0px. The bottom padding will then push the content above the original top position.

```css
.crop-top {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 0px;
  height: 7px;
  width: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<label class="crop-top">THIS TEXT IS CROPPED</label>
```

Comment: I had forgotten the overflow:hidden when I put in the code block. Short and simple solution. I like it.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the inner content in `<span>` and then using the `transform` css property you can achieve this

***Stack Snippet***

```css
body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.upper,
.bottom {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: red;
}

.bottom {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: yellow;
}

label span {
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
}

.bottom span {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label class="upper"><span>HELLO</span></label>
  <label class="bottom"><span>HELLO</span></label>
</div>
<div>
  <label class="upper"><span>WELCOME</span></label>
  <label class="bottom"><span>WELCOME</span></label>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not the same as showing the bottom half of a character. This method would only work for symmetrical characters.

Comment: @JacobPersi Updated!